# Facebook Graph API returns posts having multiple comments/likes but identical created_time & updated_time

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph API to retrieve posts from a Facebook Page using this type of URL
https://graph.facebook.com/[PageId]/posts?access_token=[access token]

This returns a number of posts such as:

```
{
   "data": [
    {
         ...
         "type": "link",
         "created_time": "2011-10-21T15:24:19+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-10-21T15:24:19+0000",
         "likes": {
            "...
            "count": 7
         },
         "comments": {
            "count": 39
         }
      },

      {
         ...
         "type": "status",
         "created_time": "2011-10-18T15:31:22+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-10-18T15:31:22+0000",
         "likes": {
            ...
            "count": 15
         },
         "comments": {
            "count": 67
         }
      },

      ...
   ],
   ...   
}
```

For every post that is returned the created_time and updated_time are identical to each other even if the post has several comments and likes attached to it! Is this a bug? Shouldn’t the updated_time of a post show the time of last comment/like/etc attached to the post?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after some more search I found out that this is a bug but only occurs if a post has more than 30 comments!

Please see here: [updated time gets reset to created_time when a post gets more than 30 comments](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/274107099276048)

Answer (score 0):

Also weird that if you have a page-feed with events in the future which were created in the past, the created and updated times are in the future, like the event dates....